# How to set deployment folder in Eclipse? (with JBoss-Wildfly)

Tags: eclipse, jboss, wildfly

I have made a couple of test projects with JavaEE / Jboss for learning purpose. In this 3rd project something is going wrong. My project is "ignored" by JBoss Wildfly. Looking inside the JBoss's deployment folder i can't see my 3rd project, no .war folder. How can i tell eclipse to deploy as usual, resulting in a new project folder in the right place under Wildfly?

I have started a new project as usual (New => Dynamic Web Project), or maybe i missed something / i have made a mistake during project creation (if yes, where?)

Answer (score 0):

Solution found. The project was never run, but only saved, so it was never deployed. Now i have the WAR folder in the selected server, and everything works!